How to replace a substring in a CLOB column in Oracle Table
I have an Oracle Table which has a CLOB column. The CLOB column has the following XML code stored -
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>41</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>BROKER</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>41</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>10 Tower Lane</Address1>
    <City>MUM</City>
    <State>MH</State>
    <ZipCode>06001</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>11</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>INSURED</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>11</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>Remond Street</Address1>
    <City>HYD</City>
    <State>HY</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>1</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>RISK</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>1</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>LOCATION</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUILDING</AddressType>
    <Address1>46 Main St</Address1>
    <City>BENG</City>
    <State>KT</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
</AddressDetails>

I want to replace the line <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
with
<SourceAddressLevelType>INSURED</SourceAddressLevelType> 

only for <SourceAddressLevel> = INSURED.
For <SourceAddressLevel> = BROKER, it should remain BUSINESS only <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
Sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (PolicyNo varchar2(10), xml_value CLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name (PolicyNo, xml_value)
SELECT 'P10001', EMPTY_CLOB() || '<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>41</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>BROKER</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>41</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>10 Tower Lane</Address1>
    <City>MUM</City>
    <State>MH</State>
    <ZipCode>06001</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>' || 
'<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>11</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>INSURED</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>11</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>Remond Street</Address1>
    <City>HYD</City>
    <State>HY</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>' || 
'<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>1</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>RISK</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>1</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>LOCATION</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUILDING</AddressType>
    <Address1>46 Main St</Address1>
    <City>BENG</City>
    <State>KT</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
</AddressDetails>' FROM DUAL;


INSERT INTO table_name (PolicyNo, xml_value)
SELECT 'P20002', EMPTY_CLOB() || '<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>26</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>BROKER</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>26</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>JP Resort</Address1>
    <City>KYN</City>
    <State>MH</State>
    <ZipCode>421301</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>' || 
'<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>90</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>INSURED</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>90</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>Solitair Park</Address1>
    <City>PUN</City>
    <State>PUN</State>
    <ZipCode>665463</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>' || 
'<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>10</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>RISK</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>10</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>LOCATION</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUILDING</AddressType>
    <Address1>Andoman Street</Address1>
    <City>AHM</City>
    <State>GUJ</State>
    <ZipCode>778753</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
</AddressDetails>' FROM DUAL;

After the change the CLOB column value should be:
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>41</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>BROKER</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>41</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>10 Tower Lane</Address1>
    <City>MUM</City>
    <State>MH</State>
    <ZipCode>06001</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>11</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>INSURED</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>11</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>INSURED</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>Remond Street</Address1>
    <City>HYD</City>
    <State>HY</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>1</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>RISK</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>1</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>LOCATION</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUILDING</AddressType>
    <Address1>46 Main St</Address1>
    <City>BENG</City>
    <State>KT</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
</AddressDetails>

and for second record
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>26</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>BROKER</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>26</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>JP Resort</Address1>
    <City>KYN</City>
    <State>MH</State>
    <ZipCode>421301</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>90</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>INSURED</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>90</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>INSURED</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>Solitair Park</Address1>
    <City>PUN</City>
    <State>PUN</State>
    <ZipCode>665463</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>
<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>10</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>RISK</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>10</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>LOCATION</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUILDING</AddressType>
    <Address1>Andoman Street</Address1>
    <City>AHM</City>
    <State>GUJ</State>
    <ZipCode>778753</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
</AddressDetails>

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Someone else may know some XML tricks, but in general, this is a good example of why storing XML like this in a relational database is usually not a good idea. You are essentially creating your own custom database within a single black box that is one obtuse data value in Oracle. All the genius of SQL to manipulate and query rows and columns is lost when we do that. So I hope you get a useful answer from someone who knows XML, but if you have the option in new development, consider using relational structures to store data so you can work with it natively.

I am assuming that your data is for 3 rows. If it is only for 1 row then your XML is invalid as XML must have only a single root element.

You can use UPDATE with an XMLQUERY and FLWOR expression:
UPDATE table_name
SET   xml_value = XMLSERIALIZE(
                    DOCUMENT
                    XMLQUERY(
                      'copy $i := $x modify (
                         for $j in $i/AddressDetails/SourceAddressLevelType
                           return replace value of node $j with $new_type
                       )
                       return $i'
                      PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_value) AS "x",
                              'INSURED' AS "new_type"
                      RETURNING CONTENT
                    )
                    AS CLOB
                    INDENT SIZE = 4
                  )
WHERE XMLEXISTS(
        '$x/AddressDetails[SourceAddressLevel="INSURED"]'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_value) AS "x"
      );

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml_value CLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name (xml_value)
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>41</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>BROKER</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>41</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>10 Tower Lane</Address1>
    <City>MUM</City>
    <State>MH</State>
    <ZipCode>06001</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>11</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>INSURED</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>11</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>
    <Address1>Remond Street</Address1>
    <City>HYD</City>
    <State>HY</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN>
</AddressDetails>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<AddressDetails>
    <SourceAddressID>1</SourceAddressID>
    <SourceAddressLevel>RISK</SourceAddressLevel>
    <SourceAddressLevelID>1</SourceAddressLevelID>
    <SourceAddressLevelType>LOCATION</SourceAddressLevelType>
    <AddressType>BUILDING</AddressType>
    <Address1>46 Main St</Address1>
    <City>BENG</City>
    <State>KT</State>
    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>
    <Country>IN</Country>
</AddressDetails>' FROM DUAL;

Then, after the UPDATE the table contains:



XML_VALUE




<AddressDetails>    <SourceAddressID>41</SourceAddressID>    <SourceAddressLevel>BROKER</SourceAddressLevel>    <SourceAddressLevelID>41</SourceAddressLevelID>    <SourceAddressLevelType>BUSINESS</SourceAddressLevelType>    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>    <Address1>10 Tower Lane</Address1>    <City>MUM</City>    <State>MH</State>    <ZipCode>06001</ZipCode>    <Country>IN</Country>    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN></AddressDetails>


<AddressDetails>    <SourceAddressID>11</SourceAddressID>    <SourceAddressLevel>INSURED</SourceAddressLevel>    <SourceAddressLevelID>11</SourceAddressLevelID>    <SourceAddressLevelType>INSURED</SourceAddressLevelType>    <AddressType>BUSINESS</AddressType>    <Address1>Remond Street</Address1>    <City>HYD</City>    <State>HY</State>    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>    <Country>IN</Country>    <PrimaryAddressYN>Y</PrimaryAddressYN></AddressDetails>


<AddressDetails>    <SourceAddressID>1</SourceAddressID>    <SourceAddressLevel>RISK</SourceAddressLevel>    <SourceAddressLevelID>1</SourceAddressLevelID>    <SourceAddressLevelType>LOCATION</SourceAddressLevelType>    <AddressType>BUILDING</AddressType>    <Address1>46 Main St</Address1>    <City>BENG</City>    <State>KT</State>    <ZipCode>05250</ZipCode>    <Country>IN</Country></AddressDetails>



fiddle

The entire XML file is stored in one record not in three different records. I have added the insert statement in the question.

@OraAff I which case, your XML is invalid as an XML document MUST have a single root element. Fix your XML first and then you can use the query in the answer (or something similar if you have wrapped it in an element).

The XML Document is very big, it cannot fit here. I have just given the part of it. Let me check if I can give the entire XML data here.

@OraAff You don't need to post it all here - you just need to make sure that there is a single element at the root - at the moment you have three <AddressDetails> elements at the root which makes the XML invalid.
